# How to achieve fast transfers over 10Gbe

Tags: networking, scp

I'm trying to transfer files over 10 gigabit ethernet. However the maximum speed I can achieve between 2 RAM-Disks (mounted on /mnt on each node) is around 200MB/s:

```
root@odin$ scp /mnt/largeFile marc@10.0.0.12:/mnt
marc@10.0.0.12's password:
largeFile                                                            86% 6904MB 192.4MB/s   00:05 ETA
```

When running Iperf I can achieve 9.89 Gb/s:

```
root@odin$ iperf -c 10.0.0.12
------------------------------------------------------------
Client connecting to 10.0.0.12, TCP port 5001
TCP window size:  325 KByte (default)
------------------------------------------------------------
[  3] local 10.0.0.11 port 59028 connected with 10.0.0.12 port 5001
[ ID] Interval       Transfer     Bandwidth
[  3]  0.0-10.0 sec  11.5 GBytes  9.89 Gbits/sec
```

The RAM-Disks achieve write speeds of 1.2 GB/s.

The network config on the 2 machines:

Server:

```
enp1s0    Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:02:c9:4d:a3:12
          inet addr:10.0.0.12  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::202:c9ff:fe4d:a312/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1
```

Client:

```
ens1      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:02:c9:4f:98:14
          inet addr:10.0.0.11  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::202:c9ff:fe4f:9814/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:9000  Metric:1
```

I'm wondering how I can achieve speeds similar to the iperf ones for file Transfers?

Answer (score 0):

It's due to the transfer limits caused by various aspects of scp/OpenSSH.

If you look at your destination machines resources while doing `lperf` and `scp` tests you should notice that even at 5x the speed the CPU will be under a lower load with `lperf` than with `scp` , this solely due to encryption.

There is a great set of resources and patches available from the Pittsburgh Supercomputing Center, https://www.psc.edu/index.php/hpn-ssh